# Nuxt and fetch hook: Property or method "$fetchState" is not defined

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a vanilla Nuxt setup and get the following error when trying to render a page using the fetch() hook:

Error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "$fetchState" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <PostDetails>
       <Nuxt>
         <DefaultLayout> at layouts/default.vue
           <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
warnNonPresent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2015
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2070
render @ _slug.vue?cd54:5
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3548
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4055
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
merged @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3301
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5978
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5925
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6516
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3948
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479
run @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4554
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4310
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1980
flushCallbacks @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1906
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1933
nextTick @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1990
queueWatcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4402
update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4544
Vue.$forceUpdate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3969
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8200
wrappedHook @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2235
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2175
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7696
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:336
whenTransitionEnds @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7391
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7728
requestAnimationFrame (async)
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7363
requestAnimationFrame (async)
nextFrame @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7362
performLeave @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7720
leave @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7704
remove$$1 @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:7797
removeAndInvokeRemoveHook @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6155
removeVnodes @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6129
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6558
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3948
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479
run @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4554
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4310
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1980
flushCallbacks @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1906
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1933
nextTick @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1990
queueWatcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4402
update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4544
notify @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:730
reactiveSetter @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1055
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2932
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2931
updateRoute @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2352
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2206
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2340
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1944
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1951
runQueue @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1955
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2335
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1944
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1948
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2322
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2105
iterator @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2300
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1947
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1951
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1948
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2322
_callee6$ @ client.js?06a0:487
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:63
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:293
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:118
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21
render @ client.js?06a0:263
iterator @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2300
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1947
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1948
eval @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2322
_callee4$ @ client.js?06a0:184
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:63
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:293
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:118
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25
Promise.then (async)
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:13
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32
eval @ asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21
loadAsyncComponents @ client.js?06a0:147
iterator @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2300
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1947
step @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1951
runQueue @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1955
confirmTransition @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2330
transitionTo @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2203
push @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2544
push @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2966
push @ router.js?5783:28
handler @ vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:1133
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6917
client.js?06a0:97 TypeError: Cannot read property 'pending' of undefined
    at Proxy.render (_slug.vue?cd54:5)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3548)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4055)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4468)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4073)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8415)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118)
    at merged (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3301)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5978)
```

Template code to render:

```
<template>
  <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">Fetching photo details...</p>
  <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">An error occurred :(</p>
  <div v-else>
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.question }}</p>
    <button @click="$fetch">Refresh</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'PostDetails',
  async fetch({ params }) {
    try {
      const postRef = await this.$fire.firestore
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(params.id)
        .get()
      const docSnapshot = postRef.data()
      this.post = docSnapshot
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error fetching post', error)
    }
    // this.post = await fetch(
    //   'https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains'
    // ).then(res => res.json())
  },
  data() {
    return {
      post: {}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Anyone spot anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling the route? fetch() hook doesn’t run on query string changes by default, could that be the issue?

Comment: Previous page has nuxt link with route param Id and sends user to this page.

Comment: So this requires to watch the query ?

Comment: Have a quick read here, see if it applies to your use case (scroll to “Listening to query string changes”). Your code looks fine to me otherwise.

Comment: figured it out...actually, very stupid mistake on my part. I'll post an answer as soon as able. Since I have access to "this" on fetch....that means i have access to this.$route.params....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the „old“ fetch definition with the context as argument.
Removing the argument from the call (and use `this`) should trigger the new fetch appropriately.